# Adding padding to simple Susy layout

Tags: css, sass, susy

Adding padding to a simple susy layout seems to break the grid for me. Adding the padding to `.item` class breaks the otherwise functioning 12-column grid.

```
$susy: (
  columns: 12,
  gutters: 1/4,
  gutter-position: split
);
$grid-padding:1em;
.wrap {
  border: 1px solid red;

  .item{
    background: lightGrey;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px; //<= THIS BREAKS THE GRID
  }
}

  .wrap {
    border: 1px solid red;
    @include container(900px);

  }

  .item {
    &.main{
      @include span(8 first);
    }
    &.side {
      @include span(4 last);
    }
  }
  .main:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear:both;
  }
```

[Meister](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/c3ab5455dac0d87e83d0ce2d90017443)

[The documentation](http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/susyone/#span-columns) kind of makes it seem as though padding can be specified as the third argument to the `span` mixin, but that isn't working for me either.

Comment: Just a tip, you're sass file needs  editing. You've used wrong indentation which is misleading, you've repeated both `.wrap` selector and `border: 1px solid red` and you haven't really taken full advantage of nesting.

Answer (score 0):

This is as simple as globally setting the [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) property with Susy's built in mixin:

```
@include global-box-sizing(border-box):
```

Or, optionally set it on only one `span` mixin

```
@include span(6 of 12 border-box)
```

[Relevant Susy docs](http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/toolkit/#global-box-sizing)

Super relevant Susy quote:

> We highly recommend using a global border-box setting, especially if you are using inside gutters of any kind.